# PHP - Doctrine Store File (Binary in Database)

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I'm looking for an example of how to store files in the database with doctrine.
Unfortunately i cannot find much information online.

I thought of a schema like:

**file**: id, fileName, fileExt, fileSize, fileMime, modifiedAt, createdAt

**fileData**: id, file_id, binaryData, modifiedAt, createdAt

Could someone give me an entity example with a function to store/retrieve files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways.

- Using [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)
- Using [lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

In both cases the main point is to open uploaded and fill its content to the entity property (after form posted but before data persisted to db). So you need to have 2 entity properties for this: uploaded file handler (not mapped to the db) and file text itself (mapped to the db).

Here is an example with the lifecycle callbacks:

**Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class SomeEntity {

    /**
     * Virtual field used for handling the file
     *
     * @Assert\File()
     */
    private $fileHandler;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function saveFileContent()
    {
        $tmpName = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.' . $this->fileHandler->guessExtension();
        try
        {
            $this->fileHandler->move(
                '../../../tmp/',
                $tmpName
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {}

        $this->setFile(file_get_contents('../../../tmp/' . $tmpName));
        unlink('../../../tmp/' . $tmpName);
    }
}
```

This also might be helpfull: **[How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)**